# There has got to be a more efficient way to do this

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, unlink

Basically I am trying to trim the images table down to 3,500 rows of unsaved or unfiltered images. Unsaved and unfiltered refer to other tables in the DB. A user can save an image as well as mark an image safe for work etc... I would like to keep all images in the saves table as well as the filter table.

Ultimately, The images table will get trimmed down to (3,500 unsaved/unfiltered images) + ("X" saved)+("X" unfiltered). The link between saves/filters/images is the auto_incremented id given to the record in the `images` table. So saves has an image_id field that gets the key of the record in the `images` table. same with the filters table

```
//connect to database
$connect = xxxxxxxxxxx;


//GET ALL IMAGES FROM `images` Table - NEWEST FIRST (`id` is auto_increment)
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$x = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    //GET CURRENT IMAGES ID AND URL
    $id = $row['id'];
    $file = $row['url'];

    //SEE IF IMAGE IS IN THE saves Table
    $saves = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `saves` WHERE `img_id` = '".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($saves) == 0){$saved = FALSE;}
    else {$saved = TRUE;}

    //SEE IF IMAGE IS IN THE filters Table
    $filter = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `filter` WHERE `img_id` = '".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($filter) == 0){$filtered = FALSE;}
    else {$filtered = TRUE;}

    //If the image has not been saved or filtered then put it in a que for deletion
    if(!$saved || !$filtered){
        $IdQue[$x] = $id;
        $FileQue[$x] = $file;
        $x++;
    }//END if   
}//END while

//Process the delete que: Delete node from database, delete file on server. Keep 3,500 of the newest images.
for($i=3500; $i<$x; $i++){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `images` WHERE id='".$IdQue[$i]."' LIMIT 1") or die("line 33".mysql_error());

    if(file_exists($FileQue[$i])){
        unlink($FileQue[$i]) or die("file Not deleted");
    }//END if
}//END for
echo ($i-3500)." files deleted<br/>";

//terminate connection
mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you arent doing all this in the query like people suggested in your question the other day?

Comment: Yes, I am having trouble with the unlink part of it

Comment: I feel that executing all those queries in the while loop section is extremely lame of me...

Comment: Can you not just make a query that returns all the urls that need deleting, then run a similar query under a delete, then delete the files? ie. two queries.

Comment: No, I would have to remove the files from the db in one pass, then read filenames from the directory where the images reside into an array, query against an array of URL's in the `images` table and unlink where file exists in directory but url does not exist in the database

Comment: How horrible is running all those queries? What if I did 3 queries and stored the results in an array, then somehow compared the arrays to find out what needs to get deleted

Comment: How about: `SELECT i.\`id\`, i.\`url\` FROM \`images\` i WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM \`saves\` s WHERE s.\`img_id\` = i.\`img_id\`) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM \`filters\` f WHERE f.\`img_id\` = i.\`img_id\`)`

Answer (score 0):

this should get you going somewhere, not a complete code though:

first, strip selecting ids down to 2 queries:

```
$missing_from_filters = SELECT id FROM images WHERE img_id NOT IN (SELECT img_id FROM filter)
$missing_from_saves = SELECT id FROM images WHERE img_id NOT IN (SELECT img_id FROM saves)
```

then, get ids that are in both arrays

```
$to_delete = array_intersect($missing_from_filters,$missing_from_saves);
```

run one query to remove them all

```
$remove_query = 'DELETE FROM images WHERE img_id IN ( '.implode(',',$to_delete).') LIMIT 3500';
```